# What is the function of the first "it" in "it is worth it"?

Tags: pronouns, dummy-it, it-its-itself

Here is a sentence in which two instances of "it" appear in the same coordinate clause:

> This job involves a lot of hard work but ***it*** is worth **it**.

Obviously, the second "it" refers back to the noun phrase "hard work". However, there is an argument about the first "it": some people say it refers back to the other noun phrase, "the job"; I don't agree and I think the first "it" serves as a dummy subject, like that which is in "It's worth sth/doing sth."  Am I right?

Comment: I can only see this: it, the job, is worth doing. The job's worth doing. *Worth it* is a set phrase that means worthwhile, rewarding, valuable in ROI. ["Because I'm Worth It."](https://www.theglobeandmail.com/life/fashion-and-beauty/beauty/loreals-because-im-worth-it-slogan-marks-a-milestone/article554604/#:~:text=But%20%22Because%20I'm%20Worth,much%20as%20a%20product%20range.)

Comment: I think that your  'obvious' interpretation is incorrect. To me the first 'it' refers to the job and the _second_ one refers to the hard work. Replacing the pronouns with the substantive ones gives "The job involves a lot of hard work but the job is worth the hard work".  Having said that you are right that "it" can be used as a dummy sometimes, just not in this case.

Comment: *This job involves a lot of hard work, but the hard work is worth doing.*

Comment: It seems blindingly obvious to me that to the extent that they "refer" to anything at all specific, *both* pronouns in the fixed expression ***It's worth it*** must refer to the same "thing". But in practice the construction isn't all that precise anyway. Usually, the most you can say about the pronoun[s] in such contexts is ***"it"** refers to the action being discussed* (where in most cases, *It's worth **it**, It's worth **doing***, and *It's worth **doing it*** are all equivalent and interchangeable).

Comment: _Worth_ is a troublesome word. It's not even clear whether it's an adjective or a preposition, and it has a **lot** of strange grammar and semantics.  I once published [a paper about the semantics of _worth, value, cost,_ and _price_](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/valueworthpricecost.pdf); the words _worthless, valueless,_ and _priceless_ are interesting related issues.

Comment: [Related](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/600416/2085).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ([Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/worth-it)) **worth it**
> enjoyable or useful despite the fact that you have to make an effort
> ♦
> It was a long climb to the top of the hill, but the view from the top was worth it.

> ([lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/worth_it)) **worth it**          
> phrase, informal
> Sufficiently good, enjoyable, or successful to repay any effort, trouble, or expense

> ([Free dictionary](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/worth+it)) **worth it**
>
> 1. Worth the cost or work involved to attain it; having benefits that outweigh the costs.
>    ♦ Getting up early to jog is tough, but it'll be worth it when you can come home from work and not have to worry about exercising.
>    ♦  This tool set cost me an entire paycheck, but it has been worth it—I've already used it for six different projects.
> 2. Worthy of something; deserving of something.
>    ♦  I know the ring is expensive, but Jane is worth it. I want her to have exactly what she wants.

According to these sources the interpretation provided by [user Yosef Baskin](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/567536/what-is-the-function-of-the-first-it#comment1408194_567536)¹ appears to be the relevant one; "worth it" has become a set expression.

¹ <sub>The first part of this interpretation, only (*worthwhile*); the example is an error if read—as I think it should be—in the light of the second definition in the preceding source (which is "**1c**" in the SOED entry (see below)—Of a person: having a certain (usu. specified) value or status, in respect of possession, property, or income; possessed of, owing.</sub>

So, the following is one possible rendering (and, of course, the first "it" stands for "the job").

- This job involves a lot of hard work but it [the job] is useful despite the effort you have to make.

> ([OALD](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/worth_1#worth_idmgs_1)) important, good or pleasant enough to make somebody feel satisfied, especially when difficulty or effort is involved
> **worth something**  [family of set phrases, "idioms" in OALD]
> ♦  Was it worth the effort?
> ♦ The new house really wasn't worth all the expense involved.
> ♦ The job involves a lot of hard work but it's worth it.
> ♦ The trip was expensive but it was worth every penny.

> (SOED) **5** Sufficiently important or valuable to be an equivalent or good return (for something); such as to justify or repay; bringing compensation for.
> ♦ B. KING  The crown of France was well worth the trouble of hearing one mass
> ♦ R. BROOK A blasphemy scarce worth me saying, A sorry jest.
> ♦ *Forbes* An engaging .. spy thriller well worth anyone's time.
> ♦ *Investors Chronicle* The extra return .. is ultimately not worth the risk.
>
> *Phrases* […]
> **worth it** *colloq* worth the time, effort, etc., spent. *worth one's* or *the [archaic] while*

According to these two additional sources, observing that nothing keeps one from using the pronoun "it" as  the  "something" to be specified, and noting the telling example in the first one of the two (fourth example), while keeping to the probably more precise definition found in "**5**" of the second of the two,  the following rendering appears also possible.

- This job involves a lot of hard work but it [the job] is valuable enough to be a good return for it [the hard work].

It becomes clear, I think, that [user Bold Ben](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/567536/what-is-the-function-of-the-first-it#comment1408195_567536)'s interpretation is just as likely a possibility; this then makes the construction disagreeably ambiguous. One can rest assured, however, that from the registers given in *lexico* and *The SOED*, in a formal context, only the latter interpretation should prevail, while in an informal one the choice might not be so easy to determine.

<sub>Note: Apparently, there is a contradiction between *the Free Dictionary* and *The SOED* as **2** in the former is a set phrase (idiom) while the corresponding **1c** in the latter is a regular meaning.</sub>

Comment: OMG, how I could misunderstand BOTH (of the “ it”)! Your answer is interesting and convincing, thanks. By the way,though I don't doubt about the definition in Cambridge Dictionary, it seems the second"it" in its example can also be construed as the  NP " a long climb to the top of the hill".

Comment: @user421993 I think so too: "the view from the top is a good return for a long climb", or in other words, ""the view from the top is  worth a long climb". // There are quite possibly subtle indications in context which will give one a certitude as to the proper interpretation, but I have not the least inkling of any; this remains confusing for me.

Answer (score 2):

I think the first "it" refers to the job. But I don't think the second "it" necessarily refers to the hard work, because something being "worth it" is a set expression, an idiom, meaning "sufficiently good, enjoyable, or successful to repay any effort, trouble, or expense."

Answer (score 0):

Consider the noun phrases "job" and "a lot of hard work" individually:

a: This job is involved but it is worth it. (By the way, "is involved" looks passive but "involved" is an adjective here - think of replacing it with "hard".)

b: This involves a lot of hard work but it is worth it.

In this case the first "it" can only refer to the preceding noun phrase; but the second "it" cannot refer to the preceding noun phrase since "job" and "a lot of hard work" are abstract things that have no intrinsic worth (other abstract things do have intrinsic worth: love, happiness, peace, contentment; and in a similar sentence, these abstract things could substitute for the second "it"). For the second "it" we are looking for something that has intrinsic worth, and we could substitute £1 million and be satisfied; but without this concrete offer we are left imagining something of worth.
If we now return to the proposed sentence, the first "it" refers to both the "job" and "a lot of hard work" since in the context they are synonymous - I could use both phrases subsequently but proximally and there would be no misunderstanding. As before, the second "it" would refer to something imagined.